# Convert console command to ODM

Tags: mongodb, odm

I'm trying to run this exact query in php with mongodb-ODM

```
db.runCommand ( { distinct: "messages",
                  key: "conversation",
                  query: { conversation: { $in: ["533f28c9211b6f7e448b4567","52cb29b0211b6fd9248b456b"] } }
                } )
```

How can I transate it with distinct() ?
thanks.

Comment: I'd start by reading your ODM's documentation, whichever it is. It would be nice to know the exact library you're using and any code you've already written to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can see My Implementation :

Define this method that execute javascript Query in mongoDB

```
/**
     * Execute javascript in mongodb
     *
     * @param string $js    JavaScript function
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function executeJs($js)
    {
        // get database name
        $mongoDatabaseName = $this->dm->getConfiguration()->getDefaultDB();
        // get connection


        $m = $this->dm->getConnection();
        // return results, get mongodb client

        return $m->getMongo()
            // select database
            ->selectDB($mongoDatabaseName)
            // execute javasctipt function
            ->command(array(
                // js
                'eval'   => $js,
                // no lock database, while js will be executed
                'nolock' => true,
            ));
    }
```

Define your String Query

```
 $_myQuery = 'function() {var messages = [];
                          db.runCommand ( { distinct: "messages",
                                            key: "conversation",
                                            query: { conversation: { $in: ["533f28c9211b6f7e448b4567","52cb29b0211b6fd9248b456b"] } }
                                          }
                                        ).forEach(function(msg){ messages[]= msg });
                            return messages; }';
```

Finally , execute your Query

```
$messageCollection = $this->executeJs($_myQuery);
if(isset(messageCollection))
    var_dump(messageCollection['retval']); // it will show result
```